# Heatsinking a TO 220 Case

Tags: transistors, pcb, heatsink

There are modules that I have purchased that are already built on a PCB, and I would like to integrate them into my board. There is a TO-220 case which is a transistor on the bottom side, and it is bent into the board(legs are bent at 90* and tab is soldered on the board). Integrating it to my existing PCB, is it possible to lay the black side/front side into a copper area? Would this help with the cooling or make no effect at all?

Comment: Is it really TO-220, or TO-263/D2PAK? (See [image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/49/TO263_beside_TO220.JPG/330px-TO263_beside_TO220.JPG))

Answer (score 1):

Anything that increases thermal mass will help with cooling, including but not limited to thermally bonding the package to another metal mass with solder or thermal paste.

Comment: Great! So I just have to add some thermal paste when I mount the board on the copper pour.

Comment: I would also use a screw or clip to hold them together tightly.